# Regular expression to generate language of natural numbers

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

Given the alphabet $\Sigma = \text{{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}$ I'm trying to find a regular expression that generates $L =\mathbb{N}$.

I can't remember the actual page I found this problem on, but their solution looks like this :

> $$0 + \text{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}[0...9]^{*}$$

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, so I'm looking for a confirmation or some sort of explanation.

As I see it, $1$ particular value at a time is taken from $\text{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}$ then any and each combination of digits from the interval $[0....9]$ is appended to it, then a $0$ may be appended, as to obtain the numbers that end in $0$.

I'm not sure of this reasoning and also I'm dubious about the fact that $[0...9]^*$ can generate sequences of identical digits preceded/followed by other digits, for instance the combination $1200009$.

Can anyone help alleviate my confusion ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a regular expression that defines a unique decimal expansion for each natural number.

Let's use the [POSIX standard for regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap09.html).
In that notation, the expression in your question is $0|([1\mbox{-}9][0\mbox{-}9]*)$ and it works likes this: it singles out zero, i.e., $0$, as a special case, and it then captures any non-zero number as a non-zero digit ($[1\mbox{-}9]$) followed by an arbitrary sequence of digits ($[0\mbox{-}9]*$).

The POSIX notation uses $|$ for your $+$ and uses square brackets as a short-hand for sets of symbols. So  $0|([1\mbox{-}9][0\mbox{-}9]*)$ is the regular expression denoting the language that you might describe in a more maths-like notation as :

$$\{0\} \cup \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \times \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}^*$$

Comment: I believe you intended to write  $0\mid(\ldots)$, not $0+(\ldots)$.

Comment: They mean the same thing in this context, I've seen them used interchangeably over several papers.

Comment: @MJD: thank you. I've updated my answer to be more precise about its use of  POSIX regular expressions.

Comment: @brian.s Rob Arthan specifically said he was using POSIX notation. In POSIX notation they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check the notation which is not the standard computer sciences notation.  From what I understand :

- $+$ is a disjunction operator with low priority.  Hence, a matching string must match either `0` or `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}[0...9]*`.
- `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` is matched by any symbol listed in the set, i.e. any decimal digit that is not $0$.
- `[0...9]` is matched by any digits between `0` and `9` i.e. any decimal digit.
- `*` means the previous pattern can be repeated arbitrarily following itself, including to have 0 successions of the pattern at all (that is, the empty string matches).  Thus `[0...9]*` would mean an arbitrary sequence of decimal figures, including no figures at all.

To sum up:

- `0` matches
- An arbitrary lengthy sequence of decimal digits matches, upon the condition that the firtst decimal digit exists and is not `0`.

I'd like to point out that you're generating the decimal notation of numbers of $\mathbb N$ without needless leading `0`.  The simple `[0..9][0...9]*` also generates notations for $\mathbb N$, although each number has in it infinitely many different notations by having arbitrarily many pointless leading zeroes.

Comment: The notation $+$ for union is standard in mathematics and theoretical computer science. See for instance [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) or [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: $+$ is used as a postfix operator indicating repetition (1 or more times) in most implementations of regular expressions. $|$ is used for union.

Comment: @RobArthan I know this, but we are on math.stackexchange and not on cs.stackexchange.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: so if you reread the first sentence of the answer that you are commenting on, don't you think your comment was a little irrelevant? (You may also like to reflect on the facts that $+$ does not denote a union operation in a general semiring or Kleene algebra and that using $+$ for union is very old-fashioned in modern mathematics.)